# Insert Multi Value Query And Skipping The Duplicate Key Vals

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, upsert

I have the following statement

select id,title from my_table

which returns a list of ids and titles, which I will need for inserting as new records into another table:

```
insert another_table (key1, key2, title) 
value                ('1', '5555', 'first'), 
                     ('2', '5555', 'second'), 
                     ('3', '5555', 'thirds'),
                     ('4', '5555', 'fourth')
```

key1 and key2 together are the key value, so in case in the values set in the previous statement runs in a compilation of these two ids which have already been used, a pg sql error occurs. I looked into Merge solution but I am not sure how to use it with multi value statements like mine. Can you assets me with this, or suggest a good, near solution? I need it so that I can still insert multi values in one query.

Thanks

Comment: what type of key is key2?

Comment: what version of PG are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**PostgreSQL 9.4+**

Assuming you have a primary key, use a `ON CONFLICT` clause:

```
insert into another_table (key1, key2, title) 
values               ('1', '5555', 'first'), 
                     ('2', '5555', 'second'), 
                     ('3', '5555', 'thirds'),
                     ('4', '5555', 'fourth'),
                     ('4', '5555', 'fourth')
                     on conflict do nothing;
```

In the statement above the **key1** (PK in my understanding) with the value **4** was given twice, but just stored once:

```
select * from another_table;

 key1 | key2 | title  
------+------+--------
 1    | 5555 | first
 2    | 5555 | second
 3    | 5555 | thirds
 4    | 5555 | fourth
```

Comment: my pg version is 9.3.19 so this gave a syntax error. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: another option is to use [anonymous code blocks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html) and catch the primary key violation exception and do what you want: `exception when sqlstate '23505' then ...`. The caveat is that it will ignore the whole insert statement, so I would use it with care. Honestly, you're missing a lot of cool features by still running postgres 9.3.  Upserts are really handy ;-)